# How to merge multiple Activitiy into one in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way to merge all activity into a single activity ? 
For e.g: I am having two pipeline (A & B) and both pipeline contain 10 - 12 activity each.
Now the problem is need to create dependency in between those two pipeline.
Once the first pipeline is successfully executed then only my second pipeline should trigger, and i didn't want those two pipeline should present in two different window.

If I am creating in single window then it looks complex, so i am planning to keep all activity of pipeline A in one box and all activity in pipeline B in another box.

So that in a single window i can see only 2 box A and B.

Can anyone know how to achieve this.

Please note: Here Box means activity which are available in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't herd any way to merge all actives into a single activity.

You purpose when the pipeline A runs succeed, then the pipeline b running.

I have some suggestions that:

1. Create a new pipeline,  using two [Execute Pipeline activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) to run pipeline A and B. 
   [image]

This is similar with you want "in a single window i can see only 2 box A and B"

For example, run the new pipeline, you can find that execute pipeline 3 is running after pipeline 2 is finished.

[image]

Hope this helps.